# objective-C - Converting an NSDate to ISO8601. How change the offset?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdateformatter

I need a string on ISO 8601  format starting from nsdate. I do that:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSString *iso8601String = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
```

The string is 2014-11-07T00:39:03+01:00. 
But I need  a format like: 2014-11-07T00:39:03+0100.
I mean, without the last semicolon. without the last semicolon.

Could I get it by formatting or simply removing the last semicolon "by hand?

Tx in advance

Comment: Look at [the docs for the date format specifier](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and look at the number of `Z` you need to get a timezone of `+0100` instead of `+01:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
```